# how to set order of array object just like response in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parsing

I am using volley class for array parsing , I am getting following  response but , I want to display in same order of array items which is in response but after parsing my array items order are not same and display random order.

```
{
  "output": {
    "status": "1",
    "GolfCourseTee": {
      "Men": [
        {
          "tee_id": 2,
          "tee_name": "Blue",
          "tee_color": "#000099"
        },
        {
          "tee_id": 4,
          "tee_name": "Yellow",
          "tee_color": "#FFFF00"
        },
        {
          "tee_id": 5,
          "tee_name": "White",
          "tee_color": "#FFFFFF"
        },
        {
          "tee_id": 1,
          "tee_name": "Black",
          "tee_color": "#000000"
        },
        {
          "tee_id": 3,
          "tee_name": "Red",
          "tee_color": "#FF0000"
        }
      ],
      "Ladies": [
        {
          "tee_id": 2,
          "tee_name": "Blue",
          "tee_color": "#000099"
        },
        {
          "tee_id": 4,
          "tee_name": "Yellow",
          "tee_color": "#FFFF00"
        },
        {
          "tee_id": 5,
          "tee_name": "White",
          "tee_color": "#FFFFFF"
        },
        {
          "tee_id": 1,
          "tee_name": "Black",
          "tee_color": "#000000"
        },
        {
          "tee_id": 3,
          "tee_name": "Red",
          "tee_color": "#FF0000"
        }
      ],
      "Junior": [
        {
          "tee_id": 2,
          "tee_name": "Blue",
          "tee_color": "#000099"
        },
        {
          "tee_id": 4,
          "tee_name": "Yellow",
          "tee_color": "#FFFF00"
        },
        {
          "tee_id": 5,
          "tee_name": "White",
          "tee_color": "#FFFFFF"
        },
        {
          "tee_id": 1,
          "tee_name": "Black",
          "tee_color": "#000000"
        },
        {
          "tee_id": 3,
          "tee_name": "Red",
          "tee_color": "#FF0000"
        }
      ]
    },
    "message": "Golf Course Tee List."
  }
}
```

Comment: When using JSON, the position of objects are preserved. JSONObject myObj = new JSONObject("{"output": "etcetcetc"}");

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("output");
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("GolfCourseTee");
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("Men");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    TeeBean typeBean = new TeeBean();
                    typeBean.setM_tee_id(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("tee_id"));
                    typeBean.setM_tee_name(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("tee_name"));
  }                   list.add(typeBean);
                }

Comment: Make use of `POJO` for storing the data.

Comment: Could you please also show how you are reading off / parsing the JSON object to display the output ?

Comment: Gson does maintain order, example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson works and maintains the order of JSON.

First, I saved the JSON into a class and used it like so:

```
public class TestJSON {

    public static String TEST_JSON_2 = "{\"output\":{\"status\":\"1\",\"GolfCourseTee\":{\"Men\":[{\"tee_id\":2,\"tee_name\":\"Blue\",\"tee_color\":\"#000099\"},{\"tee_id\":4,\"tee_name\":\"Yellow\",\"tee_color\":\"#FFFF00\"},{\"tee_id\":5,\"tee_name\":\"White\",\"tee_color\":\"#FFFFFF\"},{\"tee_id\":1,\"tee_name\":\"Black\",\"tee_color\":\"#000000\"},{\"tee_id\":3,\"tee_name\":\"Red\",\"tee_color\":\"#FF0000\"}],\"Ladies\":[{\"tee_id\":2,\"tee_name\":\"Blue\",\"tee_color\":\"#000099\"},{\"tee_id\":4,\"tee_name\":\"Yellow\",\"tee_color\":\"#FFFF00\"},{\"tee_id\":5,\"tee_name\":\"White\",\"tee_color\":\"#FFFFFF\"},{\"tee_id\":1,\"tee_name\":\"Black\",\"tee_color\":\"#000000\"},{\"tee_id\":3,\"tee_name\":\"Red\",\"tee_color\":\"#FF0000\"}],\"Junior\":[{\"tee_id\":2,\"tee_name\":\"Blue\",\"tee_color\":\"#000099\"},{\"tee_id\":4,\"tee_name\":\"Yellow\",\"tee_color\":\"#FFFF00\"},{\"tee_id\":5,\"tee_name\":\"White\",\"tee_color\":\"#FFFFFF\"},{\"tee_id\":1,\"tee_name\":\"Black\",\"tee_color\":\"#000000\"},{\"tee_id\":3,\"tee_name\":\"Red\",\"tee_color\":\"#FF0000\"}]},\"message\":\"Golf Course Tee List.\"}}";
}
```

Then I mapped the JSON to their respective models:

```
    public class Data {

        @SerializedName("output")
        Output output;

        public Output getOutput() {return output;}
    }

    public class Output {

        @SerializedName("status")
        String status;

        @SerializedName("GolfCourseTee")
        GolfCourseTee GolfCourseTee;

        @SerializedName("message")
        String message;

        public com.pearson.android.test.GolfCourseTee getGolfCourseTee() {return GolfCourseTee;}

        public String getMessage() {return message;}

        public String getStatus() {return status;}
    }

    public class GolfCourseTee {

        @SerializedName("Men")
        List<Member> Men;

        @SerializedName("Ladies")
        List<Member> Ladies;

        @SerializedName("Junior")
        List<Member> Junior;

        List<Member> cumulativeList;

        public List<Member> getAllMembers(){

            if(cumulativeList == null){  
                cumulativeList = new ArrayList<Member>();
                cumulativeList.addAll(Men);
                cumulativeList.addAll(Ladies);
                cumulativeList.addAll(Junior);
            }
            return cumulativeList;
        }

        public List<Member> getJunior() {return Junior;}

        public List<Member> getLadies() {return Ladies;}

        public List<Member> getMen() {return Men;}
    }

    public class Member {

        @SerializedName("tee_id")
        int tee_id;

        @SerializedName("tee_name")
        String tee_name;

        @SerializedName("tee_color")
        String tee_color;

        public int getTee_id() {return tee_id;}

        public String getTee_color() {return tee_color;}

        public String getTee_name() {return tee_name;}
    }
```

And here is the Activity where I use Gson:

```
    public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            try{

                Data data = gson.fromJson(TestJSON.TEST_JSON_2,Data.class);

                List<Member> mensList = data.getOutput().getGolfCourseTee().getMen();
                List<Member> ladiesList = data.getOutput().getGolfCourseTee().getLadies();
                List<Member> juniorsList = data.getOutput().getGolfCourseTee().getJunior();
                List<Member> cumulativeList = data.getOutput().getGolfCourseTee().getAllMembers();

                for(Member member : mensList)
                    Log.v("men","Id: " + member.getTee_id() + " name: " + member.getTee_name() + " color: " + member.getTee_color());

                for(Member member : ladiesList)
                    Log.v("ladies","Id: " + member.getTee_id() + " name: " + member.getTee_name() + " color: " + member.getTee_color());

                for(Member member : juniorsList)
                    Log.v("juniors","Id: " + member.getTee_id() + " name: " + member.getTee_name() + " color: " + member.getTee_color());

                for(Member member : cumulativeList){
                    Log.v("member","Id: " + member.getTee_id() + " name: " + member.getTee_name() + " color: " + member.getTee_color());
                }

            }catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is Logcat:

```
07-27 19:53:42.204 16850-16850/com.android.test V/men: Id: 2 name:Blue color:#000099
07-27 19:53:42.204 16850-16850/com.android.test V/men: Id: 4 name:Yellow color:#FFFF00
07-27 19:53:42.204 16850-16850/com.android.test V/men: Id: 5 name:White color:#FFFFFF
07-27 19:53:42.204 16850-16850/com.android.test V/men: Id: 1 name:Black color:#000000
07-27 19:53:42.204 16850-16850/com.android.test V/men: Id: 3 name:Red color:#FF0000
07-27 19:53:42.204 16850-16850/com.android.test V/ladies: Id: 2 name:Blue color:#000099
07-27 19:53:42.204 16850-16850/com.android.test V/ladies: Id: 4 name:Yellow color:#FFFF00
07-27 19:53:42.204 16850-16850/com.android.test V/ladies: Id: 5 name:White color:#FFFFFF
07-27 19:53:42.204 16850-16850/com.android.test V/ladies: Id: 1 name:Black color:#000000
07-27 19:53:42.204 16850-16850/com.android.test V/ladies: Id: 3 name:Red color:#FF0000
07-27 19:53:42.205 16850-16850/com.android.test V/juniors: Id: 2 name:Blue color:#000099
07-27 19:53:42.205 16850-16850/com.android.test V/juniors: Id: 4 name:Yellow color:#FFFF00
07-27 19:53:42.205 16850-16850/com.android.test V/juniors: Id: 5 name:White color:#FFFFFF
07-27 19:53:42.205 16850-16850/com.android.test V/juniors: Id: 1 name:Black color:#000000
07-27 19:53:42.205 16850-16850/com.android.test V/juniors: Id: 3 name:Red color:#FF0000
```

And the additional logs for member:

```
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com.android.test V/member: Id: 2 name: Blue color: #000099
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com.android.test V/member: Id: 4 name: Yellow color: #FFFF00
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com.android.test V/member: Id: 5 name: White color: #FFFFFF
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com.android.test V/member: Id: 1 name: Black color: #000000
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com.android.test V/member: Id: 3 name: Red color: #FF0000
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com.android.test V/member: Id: 2 name: Blue color: #000099
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com.android.test V/member: Id: 4 name: Yellow color: #FFFF00
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com.android.test V/member: Id: 5 name: White color: #FFFFFF
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com.android.test V/member: Id: 1 name: Black color: #000000
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com.android.test V/member: Id: 3 name: Red color: #FF0000
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com.android.test V/member: Id: 2 name: Blue color: #000099
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com.android.test V/member: Id: 4 name: Yellow color: #FFFF00
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com.android.test V/member: Id: 5 name: White color: #FFFFFF
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com,android.test V/member: Id: 1 name: Black color: #000000
07-28 13:53:10.780 6680-6680/com.android.test V/member: Id: 3 name: Red color: #FF0000
```

As you can see the order is just like in the original JSON. Hope this helps.

Edit: updated model class GolfCourseTee to return a cumulative list that is also used in TestActivity, also logs corresponding to the list added. Btw this can also be solved in other ways, solution only demonstrates one approach.

Comment: Also for this solution to work you'd need to include Gson in your project. You could get a jar from here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.7%7C or more specifically here: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.7/

Comment: but i have already use Volley class for json response and parsing .

Comment: you can use volley with gson, not a problem.

Comment: Your Volley single instance will return a JSON and gson accepts strings as input , you could pass the returned JSON from Volley's onResponse method to gson's fromJson method like so: 
fromJson(receivedJSON.toString, Data.class);

Comment: If it works, could you please accept the answer, there's the added benefit of the asker getting a couple of points.

Comment: Hey How to use Member for all like Men, Ladies and Junior

Comment: Thank you for your awesome response

Answer (score 1):

```
JsonObject jObject = new JsonObject(responseString);
JsonObject outputObject = jObject.get("output");
JsonObject golfObject = outputObject.get("GolfCourseTee");
ArrayList<GolfModel> golfList = new ArrayList<>();
JsonArray manArray = golfObject.getJsonArray("Men");
for(int i=0; i<manArray.length ;)
{
    String id = manArray.get(i).get("tee_id");
    String name = manArray.get(i).get("tee_name");
    String color = manArray.get(i).get("tee_color");
    GolfModel g = new GolfModel(id, name, color);
    golfList.add(g);
}
JsonArray ladiesArray = golfObject.getJsonArray("Ladies");
for(int i=0; i<ladiesArray.length ;)
{
    String id = ladiesArray.get(i).get("tee_id");
    String name = ladiesArray.get(i).get("tee_name");
    String color = ladiesArray.get(i).get("tee_color");
    GolfModel g = new GolfModel(id, name, color);
    golfList.add(g);
}
JsonArray juniorArray = golfObject.getJsonArray("Junior");
for(int i=0; i<juniorArray.length ;)
{
    String id = juniorArray.get(i).get("tee_id");
    String name = juniorArray.get(i).get("tee_name");
    String color = juniorArray.get(i).get("tee_color");
    GolfModel g = new GolfModel(id, name, color);
    golfList.add(g);
}
```

Comment: ***Option 2***
You can use gson library for handling json output;
These links may useful to you:
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html
https://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Leveraging-the-Gson-Library

Comment: So whats issue you are facing?

Comment: Thanks Buddy , Your code is awesome . Thank you so much for great response .